# osX - How to Start Another Program from my QT Application

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to run iBooks from my QT application.
I tried both `QProcess::execute()` and `QProcess::start()`, but none of them worked. Here is my code:

```
QString program ="/Users/muhammed/Applications/iBooks.dmg";
QStringList arguments;
QProcess *q=new QProcess(this);
q->start(program,(QStringList) arguments<<"/Users/muhammed/Applications/iBooks.dmg");
```

Nothing happens when i use this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first argument to [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) must be executable.  It looks as if you're just passing the path to a download image.

Comment: What i passed as first argument is the directory to iBooks application.

Comment: Really?  What's is output from "file /Users/muhammed/Applications/iBooks.dmg" at a command line?  Is it not something like "zlib compressed data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run a `.dmg` file directly. You need to pass the `.dmg` file path to `open` command like this:

```
$ open application.dmg
```

So, your Qt code would look like this with `QProcess::execute` static method:

```
QProcess::execute( "open", { "your-dmg-file-path-here" } );
```

Or,

```
const QString dmgPathArg { "your-dmg-file-path-here" };

QProcess process {};
process.start( "open", { dmgPathArg } );

if ( !process.waitForFinished( -1 ) )
{
    qDebug() << process.readAllStandardError();
    return;
}

qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
```

Actually, there'll be some error string that you can see using the `readAllStandardError()` and `readAllStandardOutput()` methods.

Take a look at the documentation of [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html). It has some pretty good examples to start with.

Hope that helps.